# Cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:58526 (Port shown under the Developer Mode of WSA)

Tags: windows-11

As shown in the title, I can't connect to 127.0.0.1:58526 via adb.
ADB showed

> cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:58526: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)

I checked the netstat

> netstat -anep tcp | findstr "58526"

and the result showed that Port 58526 is **not listening**(actually, I didn't get any result) .

And of course my Developer Mode is on but I **can't toggle** Wireless Debugging.

BTW, I can connect to WSA by the given IP in the WSA Setting panel(i.e.：172.22.*.*:5555).

Any suggestions on solving this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so I've been able to find a solution to the issue.

First, open a PowerShell window and run

```
ipconfig
```

You'll get a list containing lots of IP Addresses divided into categories. Look for a header with a Default tag.

[ipconfig output that you're looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE2XF.png)

Now copy the IPv4 Address that's written there.

Connect to the WSA using the following code:

```
adb connect <Your IPv4 Address>:58526
```

You'll get a prompt from WSA requesting you to allow debugging. Press Accept and you're done!

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/android/wsa/

Comment: Your solution worked well for me! I even made a video about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCKNH5ymBN0&t=198s

Answer (score 1):

The above instructions did not work for me, but what did work was following the instructions under "Disable other network adapters on the system".
https://appuals.com/no-connection-could-be-made-adb-error-10061/

To be precise:

1. I started the "Windows Subsystem for Android Settings" app.
2. I shut down WSA via the "Turn off Windows Subsystem for Android" button.
3. I disabled all network adapters except the one I was currently using (the wifi adapter in my case) (see above link for more detailed instructions).
4. I ran `.\adb connect 127.0.0.1:58526` and a pop up came up, asking me something along the lines if I trusted the device that was trying to connect.
5. I installed the APK I wanted to via `adb install`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it for me too. In my case, it was "Private Internet access" that was causing the issue. After uninstalling it, both the adb connect and the APK installer app mentioned above started to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer first: disable all you network devices, and restart WSA again.**

I have the same issue long long a ago, same as

```
netstat -anep tcp | findstr "58526"
```

and the result showed that Port 58526 is not listening(actually, I didn't get any result) .

And I can't fix it by reboot my computer, So it is a funny puzzle 'What could cause this problems, and Why?'

Yesterday, when I debug a app that need to get the right network device and listen on the ip address.
when there more the one network device, such as WIFI\cell(4G\5G)\wired\Bluetooth PAN. The code is really hard to figure the right ip address.

So, I guess the WSA has the same problem with me, when you have more the one network device, It will get the wrong ip address to bind.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it with kris' solution, but with the new Advanced Networking feature enabled there was an added wrinkle:

1. (temporarily) turn off the Advanced Networking feature under WSA System Settings
2. Restart WSA
3. *Then* use kris' solution to:

```
adb connect <Your IPv4 Address>:58526
```

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt or Powershell

C:\Users\YOUR USER FOLDER NAME\Downloads\platform-tools>adb connect 127.0.0.1:58526
already connected to 127.0.0.1:58526\

A reverse slash \ after the last 58526\ is very important.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Windows Subsystem for Android app. Navigate to "Advanced settings", expand "Experimental features" and enable "Local network access".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem from fresh install of WSA (modded on win10 with gapps though).
I could adb sometimes but could not sideload, sometimes the connection dropped.
After opening the files app in wsa settings, all was good.
I concluded that the wsa startup process was hanging or wsa wasn't even running properly unless at least one wsa app was open. As long as I have a wsa app open, i can adb no problem.

Answer (score 0):

why you peoples make your life hard `https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9MWGT0GV116F?ocid=pdpshare`

just download the apk file and it will flash it automatically scans for a any wsa connected.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this tool. but when this question was created （1 yr ago） this tool hadn't been published (as it was published in Sep 23, 2023).

Comment: Because when the adb connect doesn't work, this app doesn't work either. They both use the same mechanism. This one just gets stuck trying to start WSA, even though WSA is already running.

Comment: that tool connects through virtual serial port adb works only after the WSa is booted